# Relationship between Lambert $W$ function and Hypergeometric function

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

The Lambert $W$ Function is defined in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), while the Hypergeometric Function is defined in [this other Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). There exists also a multivariate generalization which solves the following equation
$$
e^{-c x}=d \frac{\left(x-a_{0}\right)\left(x-a_{1}\right) \cdots\left(x-a_{n}\right)}{\left(x-b_{0}\right)\left(x-b_{1}\right) \cdots\left(x-b_{m}\right)}
$$

as I read from [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/How-is-the-Lambert-W-function-derived). This equation has some analogies in Hypergeometric functions as well.

I also would like to know if the Lambert $W$ Function can be written as an inverse of Hypergeometric functions: is it so? Or are there any other kind of relationship about them? Thanks for your answers and references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q:** Can the Lambert $W$ function be written as an inverse of a hypergeometric function?

**A:** $x=W(y)$ is the solution of $_1F_1(2;1;x-1)=y/e$.

Comment: Its nice answer. thank you.I  also want to ask if there is any relationships lambert w and gaussian hypergeometric function or not. Can you suggest any  books or articles about it?@carlobeenakker

Comment: $x=y^{-1}W(-e^{-y}y)$ is the solution to $_2F_1(1,1;2;x+1)=y$.

Comment: woow that's great. thanks :) So do you have a reference? I know something about hypergeometric functions but i should study lambert w function:) @carlobeenakker

Comment: it follows directly from $_2F_1(1,1;2;x)=-x^{-1}\ln(1-x)$